# ES6 Deep Nesting SQL Query Result

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I Need help regarding an SQL result to be converted into an array of objects.

SQL returns results with these columns in JSON format:

- po_no
- po_line_no
- material_no
- material_name
- po_qty
- grpo_qty

These should be nested into:

```
po_no,
lines: {
    po_line_no,
    material_no,
    material_name,
    po_qty,
    items: {
         grpo_qty
    }
}
```

However, I don't know how to nest 3 or more levels deep using ES6.

I was using this code before,

```
Object.values(data.reduce((r, {column1,column2, column3, column4}) => {
    r[column1] = r[column1] || {column1, column2_items}
    r[column1].column2_items.push({ column2: column2 })
}))
```

But I don't know how to nest it deeper.

Comment: Use Array.prototype.map

Comment: @RidgeA do you have an example for the question above?

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/ForcefulCelebratedObservatory